# Multiple exposure blend mode information in jpeg makerdata

Tags: multiple-exposure

I want to know which blend mode (add, avg, light, dark) I have used for in-camera multiple exposure with Nikon Z6, when I view my jpeg in digikam.
I can see the number of exposures (see nikon me), but not the blend mode. Is this information stored in the jpeg makerdata ? If so, where can I find it ?
[image]

Comment: I strongly suspect the answer is "it's not stored" but please [edit your question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/posts/133088/edit) to include the exact camera model you are using.